# Does Depth First Search not add all of a node's adjacent vertices to the stack?

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I've been studying depth-first search of a graph, and I'm struggling to understand how the nodes of the graph are added to the stack.

From what I can deduce from the code, DFS should add all of a node's adjacent vertices to the stack first, as it iterates through the adjacency list until it reaches null.

Could someone please help me understand how it *doesn't* do this, but instead seems to explore one node's children / grandchildren until it reaches a leaf, and then pops off the stack to explore the next?

This is the code I'm studying:

```
    public static String dfs(Graph g) {
        String result = "";

        if (g.vertices < 1) {
            return result;
        }

        boolean[] visited = new boolean[g.vertices];

        for (int i = 0; i < g.vertices; i++) {
            if (!visited[i]) {
                result += dfsVisit(g, i, visited);
            }
        }

        return result; 
    }

    private static String dfsVisit(Graph g, int source, boolean[] visited) {
        String result = "";

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>(g.vertices);
        stack.push(source);
        visited[source] = true;

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            int currNode = stack.pop();
            result += String.valueOf(currNode);

            DoublyLinkedList<Integer>.Node temp = null;
            if (g.adjacencyList[currNode] != null) {
                temp = g.adjacencyList[currNode].headNode;
            }

            while (temp != null) {
                if (!visited[temp.data]) {
                    stack.push(temp.data);
                    visited[temp.data] = true;
                }
                temp = temp.nextNode;
            }
        }
        return result;    
    }
```

From what I can tell, in the inner while loop, shouldn't we push all of a node's adjacent vertices? So e.g. if my graph is:

```
0 --> 1 --> 2 --> null
1 --> 3 --> null
2 --> 4 --> null
3 --> 4 --> null
4 --> null
```

When starting at node 0, I would expect 1 and 2 to be put in the stack as they are the adjacent vertices of 0. But from what I've seen in other resources, it should put 1 in the stack, and then 3 in the stack, and then 4, and then it has reached a leaf so it backtracks?

I understand that this is how DFS works, but can't quite get my head around the stack ordering.

Any help appreciated - thanks!

Comment: _Could someone please help me understand how it ... seems to explore one node's children / grandchildren until it reaches a leaf_ That's how DFS works. Keep descending each node's first child until you reach a node that has no children and then backtrack. There are many online resources [explaining DFS](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=depth+first+search+explained). I suggest you keep searching until you find one that explains it in a manner that you can understand.

Comment: @Abra my question wasn’t clear, apologies. I understand how DFS works, in that it backtracks once it reaches a leaf node, and then explores other nodes and their children / grandchildren. But my confusion comes from the code itself - would the inner while loop not add ALL of a node’s adjacent nodes to the stack? That’s how it reads to me - it will put all of a node’s adjacents in the stack, and will stop once there are no other adjacents. Then it pops from the stack and does the same with this new node’s adjacents. How does that equate to the concept of exploring children first, not adjacents?